# Recover tokens from base Network to Ethereum mainnet

Tags: tokens, etherscan, recover

I just sent a few days ago some Ethereum through base Network because the fees were low to an account that's does not support Base. My private keys are held by the exchange because it's a custodial wallet under Revolut company. I have openness from them to recover the tokens back to Ethereum mainnet but I need a very good procedure to do so.

The transaction hash result can only be seen in base Network through basescan. As far as it concerns to Etherscan, the hash can't be found.

Well I know that there are some ways though coding that well implemented can recover the funds from the base Network assignment back into Ethereum mainnet reassigning them to the same wallet address.

Is there anybody who can help me with a way even with coding so I can send it to their support?
The development team they are open to resolve this issue, though giving me the private keys is against their terms and conditions agreement they're still open to receive informations from to solve this issue without giving a full support to base base Network.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: To recover tokens from the recipient address you need the private key associated with it. Without those credentials there's nothing you could do.